# Having an issue with my Web site loading. This is a .SWF file embedded into the index.html

Tags: html, css, javascript, flash, xhtml

My Web site http://www.KushKouture.com/ does not seem to load correctly in ANY web browser. The flash seems to be there, as I can right click to get the flash options as expected, but the .SWF does not play.

I have included the code from the index.html below for your review. Not sure if anything is missing/incorrect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="author" content="Kush Kouture" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Kush Kouture, men's lifestyle and street apparel clothing company" />
<meta name="description" content="Kush Kouture is an upcoming, upmarket men's lifestyle and street apparel clothing company. The brand is exclusively manufactured in the UK and currently, based solely online. Inspired by the 'Lifestyle' culture, the brand has conceived its designs based on influences from a variety of musical genres ranging from Punk Rock to Hip-Hop, along with many traits from today's teen demographic." />

<title>Kush Kouture</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfaddress.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">   
var flashvars = {};   
flashvars.url_config = "xml/configuration_site.xml";   
flashvars.initServices = true;   
var params = {};   
params.allowfullscreen = true;   
params.allowScriptAccess = "always";
params.play = true;   
var attributes = {};   
attributes.id = 'flashObject';   
attributes.bgcolor = '#000000';   

swfobject.embedSWF("index.swf", "flashContent", "100%", "100%", "8",false, flashvars, params, attributes);  
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    /* hide from ie on mac \*/
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #flashContent {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* end hide */

    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    p {

    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    line-height:17px;
    color:#ffffff;

} 
.style1 {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="flashContent">
<p style="color:#999999">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kush Kouture | You require the latest version of Adobe Flash Player. Please click the image below to download this.</p>   
<p><a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/"><img src="flash.jpg" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
</div>   

</body>
</html>
```

I hope somebody will be able to help! Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what type of server your using? If IIS, you need to make sure that it's set up to work with your file extensions.

Comment: I am currently hosting my website with 1and1.co.uk not sure on their setup, but I would assume they support all types of web sites and I have had it working before only in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The flash file is being loaded and it does play.

If you press the tab key a couple of times, flash accesibility helper is activated an you can see a yellow rectangle marking where the fullscreen button is.

My guess is that the menu system is not loading becouse you have a syntax error in one of the -many- XML files.

Comment: ah I see exactly what you mean! I will check the XML files now! really appreciate that.. can i just ask, does my code look correct in regards to embedding the .SWF and the 'swfobject.embedSWF'